# ng-Grid 'Selection' wont show up in browser using Flask

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

Using Master/Details Example on pluker
http://plnkr.co/edit/CncDWCktXTuBQdDVfuVv?p=preview

I copied everthing local file and just launching the html 
in firefox and chrome. Everything works.

But when I try to server the page via a Flask python server. I
dont see selection in html as output.  It looks like that {{ ?? }}
in not showing up....

app.py: trimmed down flask app

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, json, Response

app = Flask(__name__)
DEBUG = True

@app.route("/index", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def selected_version():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/newAppMain.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        <div class="selectedItems"> {{mySelections}} </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The view Source of index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
        <head lang="en">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/newAppMain.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
            <div class="selectedItems"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what does `I dont see selection in html as output` mean?

Comment: In plunker when you select an item, The output is in the selection div. If running from localhost:5000, when I select something, there is no ouput. When running from file:// everything works.

Comment: everything else works? Any errors in browser console?

Comment: Including stack trace in question. this wasnt there ystr.

Comment: I suggest you share with us the actual HTML+JS that is being returned when you open http://loc4alhost:5000/index/ .

Comment: Its the same exact as plunker code.

Comment: Maybe this helps, when opening file I get [] for selection, But I server the page I get nothing.